# ¿Como hago una consulta a dos tablas con una columna que se llama igual?

Tags: sql-server, asp

Lo que quiero es que con estas dos tablas vea si en la columna(que es igual en las dos) sea igual a un request.form

Por ahora tengo esto pero me marca este error Ambiguous column name 'Punto_Tactico'.

```
set rs_pTactico = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql_pTactico = "SELECT * FROM Infraestructura, Equipos WHERE 
Punto_Tactico='" & request.form("Punto_Tactico") & "'"
rs_pTactico.Open sql_pTactico,conn,3,3
```

También he probado de esta forma con inner join, aqui no me da problemas pero solo hace la consulta con la tabla infraestructura y yo quiero que sea en ambas, pero no se como hacerlo

```
set rs_pTactico = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql_pTactico = "SELECT * FROM Infraestructura INNER JOIN Equipos ON 
Infraestructura.Punto_Tactico='" & request.form("Punto_Tactico") & "'"
rs_pTactico.Open sql_pTactico,conn,3,3
```

Comment: cuál es la condición de join de las tablas?, eso no queda claro

Comment: @Lamak la verdad nunca había usado el inner join, es lo que pude encontrar mas o menos por internet, lo único que quiero es que la consulta a mis dos tablas Equipos e Infraestructura sea igual a su respectiva columna "Punto_Tactico" para que con el request.form compruebe si hay en información en esas dos tablas

Comment: Es que con `INNER JOIN` o sin, se necesita esta condición (sin el `INNER JOIN` explícito, como lo haces en tu primera consulta, iría en el `WHERE`

Comment: @Lamak a que te refieres con la condición, me podrías dar un ejemplo? soy nuevo en esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta de esta forma

```
set rs_pTactico = server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sql_pTactico = "SELECT * FROM Infraestructura INNER JOIN Equipos ON 
Infraestructura.Punto_Tactico=Equipos.Punto_Tactico where Equipos.Punto_Tactico ='" & request.form("Punto_Tactico") & "'"
rs_pTactico.Open sql_pTactico,conn,3,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Independientemente del resto de la consulta, cuando utilizas instrucciones JOIN, en la clausula select es recomendable utilizar la notación `tabla.columna` por ejemplo `Infraestructura.Punto_Tactico` o también puedes usar alias como se detalla aquí:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

El resto de problemas te derivan de en el primer caso estas generando un producto cartesiano de todas las columnas de las tablas. En el segundo caso es posible que tengas problemas por la condición de unión de las tablas.

La solución más lógica sería, sabiendo la estructura de las tablas, buscar la instrucción JOIN que necesites, estas últimas puedes consultarlas aquí:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp